# Flash - Keyboard event doesn't fire

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm working on a website with multiple Flash animations. One of them is a visual numeric keyboard but I want it to catch physical keystrokes also.

The problem is that when I try it with Adobe Flash it works great but when it's running in a Browser (Firefox or IE11) physical inputs are not caught.

Here is my keylistner (in AS2 sorry ^^'):

```
clavierListen = new Object();
clavierListen.onKeyDown = function() {
    keya = Key.getCode();
    if (keya>=48 && keya<=57) {
        switch (keya) {
        case 48: chiffrage(0); btn_clavier0.gotoAndPlay(2); break;
        case 49: chiffrage(1); btn_clavier1.gotoAndPlay(2); break;
        case 50: chiffrage(2); btn_clavier2.gotoAndPlay(2); break;
        case 51: chiffrage(3); btn_clavier3.gotoAndPlay(2); break;
        case 52: chiffrage(4); btn_clavier4.gotoAndPlay(2); break;
        case 53: chiffrage(5); btn_clavier5.gotoAndPlay(2); break;
        case 54: chiffrage(6); btn_clavier6.gotoAndPlay(2); break;
        case 55: chiffrage(7); btn_clavier7.gotoAndPlay(2); break;
        case 56: chiffrage(8); btn_clavier8.gotoAndPlay(2); break;
        case 57: chiffrage(9); btn_clavier9.gotoAndPlay(2); break;
        }
    }

}
Key.addListener(clavierListen);
```

Is there a particular configuration necessary to make it work in a browser ?

Comment: You code looks fine. In the browser you should "select" your swf to get the focus and be able to catch your keyboard input ...

Comment: @akmozo The point is that I have many flash animations running on the same page (and I think some of them are catching focus). I can't edit those other animations, is there a way to force mine to get the focus ?